# How to display video in wpf page

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core-3.1

I have a video which I want to display in a page in my Window included by a frame as below:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="stackAds" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"  
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Grid.Column="0">
      <Border BorderBrush="Transparent" 
              BorderThickness="1">
          <Frame Source="/MyPage.xaml">
          </Frame>
      </Border>
</StackPanel>
```

I tried to use MediaElement in my Page

```
<MediaElement Source="/Media/MyVideo.mp4"
            Visibility="Visible" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
            Stretch="Fill" 
            Height="599" 
            LoadedBehavior="Play"/>
```

I have changed my video Build Action property to "Content" and CopyToOutputDirectory to "Copy always" based on [MediaElement Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.mediaelement?view=netcore-3.1) documentation, but when i run my application the page display nothing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found my answer already.
removing the "/" from my MediaElement.Source